# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type on stub of gettimeofday

Tags: c

Haven't done much c programming and am running into "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type".
Attempting to stub out gettimeofday with call to clock_gettime.

Here is code

```
#include <time.h>

int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz)
/* This procedure stubs out call to gettimeofday */
{
   struct timespec spec;

   // initialize result status to invalid
   int result = -1;

   // if passed in pointer tv is not NULL
   if (tv) {
      // retrieve time
      result = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);

      // if time retreived is valid then
      if (result == 0){

         tv->tv_sec = spec.tv_sec;   // seconds
         tv->tv_usec = (spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e3);  // Convert nanoseconds to microseconds
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

I get the "error dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" on assignment

```
tv->tv_sec = spec.tv_sec;   // seconds
```

If I compile/link in linux target=i686-pc-linux-gnu but no error intarget=powerpc-xcoff-lynxos178 target environment.

I am #include  and that has definition timespec

time.h is different for each target. Thank you for taking time to look at this.

Comment: You're missing a definition of `struct timeval`

Comment: Maybe timespec  is different too.

Comment: POSIX says `struct timeval` is defined in `<sys/time.h>`.

Comment: So did `#include <sys/time.h>` fix the problem?

Comment: #include <sys/time.h> did not fix the problem  - I apologize but I don't have the a log with the actual error message all it shows is  that it did not compile

Answer (score 0):

Along with the need for `#include <sys/time.h>` you are probably seeing a conflict with the prototype for the system's `gettimeofday()` call.  On many systems the second parameter is `void *`.

Comment: Thx Greg that is what we discovered.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for this stub of gettimeofday was we were trying to write the stub to work in 3 different environments. Windows, Linux target and powerpc target - each of which seems to have slight variants in OS headers. What we ended up doing was adding a compiler directive to handle linux vs the other environments where we did not have issues. This is ultimately what we went with - I thought we should have avoided the stub and just called clock_gettime but there were reasons why this way was cheaper.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#ifdef __linux__
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *__restrict __tv, __timezone_ptr_t __tz)
#else
int gettimeofday(struct timeval * __tv, struct timezone* __tz)
#endif
```